# Time complexity analysis of random forest and k-means?

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity, clustering, decision-trees

I am working with random forest for a supervised classification problem, and I am using the k-means clustering algorithm to split the data at each node, where

- $n$ is the number of points,
- $K$ is the number of clusters,
- $I$ is the number of iterations,
- $d$ is the number of attributes.

I am trying to calculate the time complexity for the algorithm

1. From what I understand the time complexity for $k$-means is $O( n \cdot K \cdot I \cdot d )$ , and as $k$, $I$ and $d$ are constants or have an upper bound, and $n$ is much larger than these three, i suppose the complexity is just $O(n)$.
2. The random forest on the other hand is a divide and conquer approach, so for $n$ instances the complexity is $O(n\cdot \log n)$, though I am not sure about this, correct me if i am wrong.

To get the complexity of the algorithm do i just add these two things?

Comment: Actually, $I$ could be exponential in $n$ if you run the algorithm to completion.

Comment: What do you mean with "the random forest a divide and conquer approach"?

Answer (score 0):

as it has been mentioned in the comment section, '**I**' can be exponential in `n` if you run the algorithm to completion. which means you can't just cut down `O(n.K.I.D)` to be `O(n)`.
number of iterations can be just a big factor in your complexity.

for the second part I would also say no, you can't add the complexity like this.

let's say that your `k-means` is refining your data. Then, your `n` would become a `j` where: `n >= j` when you reach your `random forest`. so what you can say that the complexity here is:

`O(n.K.I.D) + O( j.log j)` where `j <= n`

I really don't have a valid proof here. but when you look at it. it just makes sense.